# Groovy HTTP Builder: Catching invalid formatted JSON response

Tags: json, groovy, httpbuilder

Hi I'm using Groovy HTTPBuilder to make a POST call similar like this:

```
   http.request( POST, JSON ) { req ->
        body = [name:'testName', title:'testTitle']
         response.success = { resp, json ->
            println resp.statusLine
            println json
        }
    }
```

However due to a Bug (which I cannot solve myself), the REST server returns a JSON that is not correctly formatted resulting in the following exception when my application is trying to parse it:

groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

I'm fairly new to groovy closures and HTTPBuilder, but **is there a way to make the application check if the JSON is actually valid before parsing it and returning null if so?**

Comment: regardless if there is a config, you could do try/catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, but it is possible to supply your own JSON parser, which facilitates the original request. It also affords the opportunity to "fix" the JSON if the known bug *can be fixed*.

Example below. The parser is essentially the same code that [HTTPBuilder uses](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/blob/master/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/ParserRegistry.java), with the exception of a hard-coded charset of `UTF-8`.

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7' )

import groovy.json.*

import groovyx.net.http.*
import static groovyx.net.http.Method.*
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

def url = "http://localhost:5150/foobar/bogus.json"

def http = new HTTPBuilder(url)

http.parser."application/json" = { resp ->
    println "tracer: custom parser"
    def text = new InputStreamReader( resp.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");
    def result = null
    try {
        result = new JsonSlurper().parse(text)
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // one could potentially try to "fix" the JSON here if
        // there is a known bug in the server
        println "warn: custom parser caught exception"
    }

    return result
}

http.request( POST, JSON ) { req ->
    body = [name:'testName', title:'testTitle']
     response.success = { resp, json ->
        println resp.statusLine
        println json
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks solved the problem :) I can definitely see why its not a good idea though..